# Scaled Container Overlapping Parent-widget flutter

Tags: flutter, widget, overlap

How do I make this blue-circle not overlap the green-box, but insted be confined to the inner bounderyes of the green-box?

> Code:

```
Container(
  width: 300,
  height: 100,
  color: Colors.green,
  child: Transform.scale(
     scale: 2,
     child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
        color: Colors.blue
        ),
     ),
  ),
),
```

> Pictures tells the rest:

[image]

Thx already

*- Tobias*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to do this using ClipRect widget with hardEdge on clipBehaviour property.

```
Center(
    child: Container(
      width: 300,
      height: 100,
      color: Colors.green,
      child: ClipRect(
        clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
        child: Transform.scale(
          scale: 2,
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              shape: BoxShape.circle,
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
```